# Binary bomb phase 3 issue

Tags: c, assembly, binary-bomb

I am trying to complete a binary bomb exercise, and I have made it through the first 2 phases but I am stuck on how to even being solving it, as all the guides I have found feature a different assembly code and none of the same variables. I'm not asking for someone to solve the problem for me or anything, just how to go about actually finding the answer (i.e. what commands I would need to try or variables to focus on).

I've tried finding variables that correspond to hexadecimal letters when using x/s ___ but I've had no luck getting it correspond to lowercase letters. I've tried on my own for 3 hours to figure out this phase and I've had no luck. Here is the assembly language for phase 3:

```
08048c17 <phase_3>:
 8048c17:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048c18:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048c1a:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
 8048c1d:   8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 8048c20:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
 8048c24:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048c27:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048c2b:   c7 44 24 04 7e 94 04    movl   $0x804947e,0x4(%esp)
 8048c32:   08 
 8048c33:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048c36:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048c39:   e8 a2 f9 ff ff          call   80485e0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
 8048c3e:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 8048c41:   7f 05                   jg     8048c48 <phase_3+0x31>
 8048c43:   e8 09 02 00 00          call   8048e51 <explode_bomb>
 8048c48:   83 7d f4 07             cmpl   $0x7,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048c4c:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 8048c50:   77 6a                   ja     8048cbc <phase_3+0xa5>
 8048c52:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048c55:   ff 24 85 e0 93 04 08    jmp    *0x80493e0(,%eax,4)
 8048c5c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c61:   eb 52                   jmp    8048cb5 <phase_3+0x9e>
 8048c63:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c68:   eb 46                   jmp    8048cb0 <phase_3+0x99>
 8048c6a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c6f:   90                      nop
 8048c70:   eb 39                   jmp    8048cab <phase_3+0x94>
 8048c72:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c77:   eb 2d                   jmp    8048ca6 <phase_3+0x8f>
 8048c79:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c7e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048c80:   eb 1f                   jmp    8048ca1 <phase_3+0x8a>
 8048c82:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c87:   eb 13                   jmp    8048c9c <phase_3+0x85>
 8048c89:   b8 6d 03 00 00          mov    $0x36d,%eax
 8048c8e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 8048c90:   eb 05                   jmp    8048c97 <phase_3+0x80>
 8048c92:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048c97:   2d c5 02 00 00          sub    $0x2c5,%eax
 8048c9c:   05 94 03 00 00          add    $0x394,%eax
 8048ca1:   2d e2 00 00 00          sub    $0xe2,%eax
 8048ca6:   05 e2 00 00 00          add    $0xe2,%eax
 8048cab:   2d e2 00 00 00          sub    $0xe2,%eax
 8048cb0:   05 e2 00 00 00          add    $0xe2,%eax
 8048cb5:   2d e2 00 00 00          sub    $0xe2,%eax
 8048cba:   eb 0a                   jmp    8048cc6 <phase_3+0xaf>
 8048cbc:   e8 90 01 00 00          call   8048e51 <explode_bomb>
 8048cc1:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048cc6:   83 7d f4 05             cmpl   $0x5,-0xc(%ebp)
 8048cca:   7f 06                   jg     8048cd2 <phase_3+0xbb>
 8048ccc:   3b 45 f0                cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 8048ccf:   90                      nop
 8048cd0:   74 05                   je     8048cd7 <phase_3+0xc0>
 8048cd2:   e8 7a 01 00 00          call   8048e51 <explode_bomb>
 8048cd7:   c9                      leave  
 8048cd8:   c3                      ret
```

Here is the guide I have been provided for phase 3, it seems very valuable but I am having trouble understanding how to apply it to my code given the different variables/values. Here are screen caps of what I think are the most relevant parts, and the full link to the guide below those screen caps: [Introductory guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P034h.png)

[Guide part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQoFI.png)

[Guide part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDEMt.png)

[Here is a full link to the guide](http://zpalexander.com/binary-bomb-lab-phase-3/)

The goal is to have a number followed by a lowercase letter and then followed by a number (like 1 v 240 or 4 b 60). But I haven't been able to find any numbers or a letter.

Comment: Note: you can [edit] your question to clarify it. I think it could be an interesting question if only it was clear.

Comment: Read the code or use your debugger to figure out where `sscanf` places the values it has read (knowledge of calling conventions helps a lot here). Then follow the code to figure out what's being done with those  values. Knowing that should tell you which values allow you to pass without calling `explode_bomb`. There's really not much more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was mistaken on the method, and the problem was actually looking for a pair of numbers without a letter. For those wondering, I found the solution by following the scanf assembly sections like was suggested by De Dycker, and ended up charting the first number followed by finding the second pair through trial and error.

Comment: You could have found the second value without trial and error. The clue is in `jmp    *0x80493e0(,%eax,4)`, which uses the first number as an index into a jump table. And then follow the logic.